# Inserting new data in mysql after creating new field

Tags: mysql

How can I insert new data in column after adding column without using update function. for example 
"`alter table Employee add column Gender varchar(1) after Birthdate` then I get wrong when I used this statement `insert into Employee(ENumber,EmpName,Birthdate,Address,Salary,DNumber,Gender)
    -> values
    -> ('E001','GSInocencio','1988-01-15','Munoz',18000,'D005','F'),`
It gives me error `Duplicate entry 'E001' for key 'PRIMARY'
MariaDB [Employees_Valdez]>`

Comment: I don't understand, how your error is related to creating a new column. You wouldn't be able to insert that row even before you added the `Gender` column. All I can think is that you actually want to update an existing row. But then it wouldn't make sense if you want to do that "without using update".

Answer (score 1):

The messages is pretty clear: You already have an employee with that ENumber value.

You have a `UNIQUE` constraint on that column, it's a `PRIMARY KEY`, so either pick a different value, or use a different primary key.

One thing to note is MySQL doesn't use complex string primary keys very efficiently, they're also a real hassle for relating data since they're so big. It's usually better to include a standard `id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` column and then have things like `ENumber` being a secondary `UNIQUE` constraint.

You can then relate data using the 4-byte `id` value, or 8-byte if `BIGINT` is a concern like you might have two billion employees.